# SQL to see if 'ANY' rows match the criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

given the following SQL in Postgres, I want to see if **any** row matches the criteria and not interested in **what** rows match. e.g. in this case, (if i have any perishable stock)

The only way i have achieved this is use the limit clause but its very slow (there is >100,000,000 records)

```
select is_perishable
from stock
where is_perishable = true
limit 1;
```

Is there a quicker, more eloquent method in achieving this?

Comment: you can add an index for that if you don't have already .

Comment: Is there an index on the `is_perishable` column?

Comment: @kmoser - yes..

Comment: Define "slow"..

Comment: Also, when you say "it's indexed"! do you mean "the column has its own index or appears as the first column in a multi column index" or do you mean "there is some multicolumn index that mentions this column but not as the first column" (because in that case i'd be very surprised if it's actually being used)

Comment: @Caius - part of a multi-column so i'm reindexing to see if the it improves the speed (multi second return times) but I like your approach as its better illustrates the queries intentions.. after that, i'll review the query planner.. thanks for this..

Comment: Generally indexes are only usable in left to right order, so an index on `Person(gender, age, name)`  probably couldn't be used for a `WHERE name = 'x'` (realistically it'd only usable thus if there were very few values of gender/age and the DB knew that), but it could be used for `WHERE gender = 'x'` or `WHERE gender = 'x' AND age = 'x'`. Strive to order your indexes so they're reusable for as many different queries as possible, as it reduces the number of indexes you need to keep. Sometimes you can bring an index into use by adding dummy values to a query for example knowing you want all..

Comment: ..20 years old people called John, and gender is always (for example) 1, you can put the gender clause into the where (even though it's "useless" from a resultset perspective because all rows are gender 1) to encourage the use of a gender/age/name index. *Note this comment is not intended to be gender divisive against people named John that happen to identify as a gender other than 1 :)

Comment: Did you try a filtered index? `create index on stock (some_column) where is is_perishable` This would be especially efficient if only a (relatively) small percentage of the rows have `is_perishable  = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try EXISTS:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  select null from stock where is_perishable = true
)
```

How much faster it'll be, if at all, I've no idea, but it ought to be optimized to quit early upon assessing the presence of a record.. Though so would a limit query... If it's no different, post the query plan

Comment: i don't think this will be faster in anyway

Comment: Me neither, but I can't understand why the limit version would be slow

Comment: @Mannie . . . Because you accepted this answer, it would be nice if you elaborated on the difference in performance between your solution and this solution.

Answer (score 1):

this might be a little bit faster :

```
select 1
from stock
where is_perishable = true
limit 1;
```

nevertheless it can be slow if there is no row with is_perishable = true.
here a proper index can be helpful.